# How to bold/keep measure names in r after merging on common columns

Tags: html, r, html-table, format, r-markdown

If I have two dataframes:

```
tibble1 <- tibble("DoB" = c("Year", "Month"),
                  "Bob" = c("2001", "3"),
                  "Kevin" = c("1999", "9"), 
                  "Stewart" = c("1868", "11"))
tibble2 <- tibble("Education" = c("School", "Degree"),
                  "Bob" = c("UNIV", "BA"),
                  "Kevin" = c("CC", "AD"), 
                  "Stewart" = c("GS", "PHD"))
```

And I do rbind on Bob, Steward, Kevin, how would I output a table that looks like the following:
[image]
I've tried creating rownams on the variable measures, but not sure how to retain the differing column names & bolding them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` `flextable` solution:

1. After binding both tibbles we use coalesce to create `Variables` column.
2. We group by 2 rows and bring the tibble in shape with select
3. we use `group_modify` to add a row in first place to each group
4. with a `case_when` statement we hard code the names `DoB` and `Education`.
5. Next part is to get bold column names and row names with `flextable`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)

bind_rows(tibble1, tibble2) %>% 
  mutate(Variables = coalesce(DoB, Education)) %>% 
  group_by(group =as.integer(gl(n(),2,n()))) %>% 
  select(Variables, Bob, Kevin, Stewart, group) %>% 
  group_modify(~ add_row(.x,.before=0)) %>% 
  mutate(Variables = case_when(is.na(Variables) & group == 1 ~ "DoB",
                               is.na(Variables) & group == 2 ~ "Education", 
                               TRUE ~ Variables)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-group) %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  bold(bold = TRUE, part = "header") %>% 
  bold(i = ~ Variables %in% c("DoB", "Education"), bold = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is super helpful for what I wanted-- followup: if I had groups with different lengths, how could I add that in? E.g. these groups have 2 groups each, but what if I added in a group with 3 subgroups?